# Помогите разобраться с MySQL. Почему выдаёт ошибки?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

В таблице по порядку идут поля:
id, first_name, last_name, status, reg_date(дата регистрации).
При запросе:
"INSERT INTO clients VALUES ('Peter', 'King', 'user', NOW());"
Выдаёт вот такую ошибку:
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.
Я так понимаю, это из-за того, что я пропускаю первичный ключ, но разве обязательно его вводить, если он и так сам по себе увеличивается и в поле не стоит NOT NULL? И что делать в таком случае? Всё время писать в скобочках вставляемые атрибуты? Это же неудобно ;(

Answer (score 4):

Варианты:

1. Указать заполняемые поля. См. [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/923109/229437) от [Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176262/igor). Копия его кода:

   ```
   INSERT INTO clients (first_name, last_name, status,  reg_date)  
   VALUES ('Peter', 'King', 'user', NOW());
   ```

   К слову, в этом варианте можно избавиться и от поля `reg_date` в тексте запроса, если установить ему `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, и передавать только 3 значения трём полям.
2. Явно присвоить значение полю `id`. Т.е. добавить в запрос пятое (правда, по счёту самое первое) значение. Правда, откуда бы его взять... Код:

   ```
   INSERT INTO clients 
   VALUES (123456789, 'Peter', 'King', 'user', NOW());
   ```
3. То же, что и 2, но в качестве значения  указать `NULL`. В этом случае автоинкремент сработает так же, как и в варианте 1 - штатно присвоит очередное значение. Код:

   ```
   INSERT INTO clients 
   VALUES (NULL, 'Peter', 'King', 'user', NOW());
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Если `id` автоинкрементное поле:

```
INSERT INTO clients  
       (first_name, last_name, status,  reg_date)  
VALUES ('Peter',    'King',    'user',  NOW())
```